# Failed to codesign '/.iOS.app': .iOS.app: cannot find code object on disk

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I have been struggling with this for over a week.  Had to purchase a new windows development laptop and unfortunately now can’t distribute iOS app to the app store.  I have tried every suggestion I can find online however nothing seems to work.  This includes all new keys, both development and distribution, intermediate certs, path file lengths, the codesign environment variable, locking keychain, etc.  My environment is as follows:

Visual Studio 2022  17.4
Xamarin.IOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK – 16.0.0.92
SDK Version 14.4 - From iOS Build screen

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, I’m stuck and can longer distribute app updates, very frustrating…

What I've tried

cleared all keys from keychain
created all new dist certs and keychains
deleted obj and bin folders
locked keychain access / unlocked keychain access

Comment: this is an error from the iOS build chain on your mac, it shouldn't have anything to do with your Windows PC

Comment: I saw that you posted the same ['/usr/bin/codesign ''.iOS.app: cannot find code object on disk' thread in Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1098258/usrbincodesign-3939iosapp-cannot-find-code-object.html), let's focus on that one.

Comment: I have the same issue and didn’t find a fix yet…

Comment: @mbs9  May I know that have you fixed the issue?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I have cloned the Git repository on my Mac device, and invoked the build from the .Net CLI on my Mac, instead of letting VS from my Windows do this. So instead of creating a connection between VS on windows and my Mac, I invoked the build manually using .net on my Mac.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Otherwise I don’t know how to properly fix the issue such that I can use Windows VS’s connect to Mac feature. I essentially had to build it manually from CLI on Mac